# Открывать ссылки на другие сайты не в WebView, а в обычном браузере

Tags: java, android

Нужно чтобы при нажатие на любую ссылку, которая не ведет на страницы сайта http://site.com, запускался выбор браузеров для открытия сайта.

Все приложение эта мобильная версия сайта упакованная в webview, чтобы не нарушать целостность все ссылки которые идут не на домен сайта нужно открывать в браузере, а не в приложение.

Код программы:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private  WebView web;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
        web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        web.loadUrl("https://site.com");
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (web.canGoBack()) {
            web.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно описать `WebViewClient` подобным образом:

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.example.com")) {
            // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
            return false;
        }
        // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
}
```

И, соответственно установить его в `WebView`:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

Answer (score 0):

Если кратко, то так:

```
// В этой переменной у нас хранится адрес сайта
String site = "http://site.com/";

Uri siteUri = Uri.parse(site);

// Создаём интент
Intent openLinkIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, siteUri);

// Открываем в браузере
startActivity(openLinkIntent);
```

Стоит заметить, что если для ссылок данного вида в системе есть несколько приложений, покажется меню для выбора подходящего (если не установлено приложение по умолчанию).

А метод `startActivity` есть у `Context` (если вы вдруг будете вызывать его вне класса активити).

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы в браузере открывались все сайты кроме этого, а этот сайт только в текущем webview

Comment: @Slaxor где у вас будут храниться эти ссылки? У вас будет длинный текст, в котором могут содержаться ссылки? Или что? Если нет, то можете обрабатывать сначала, на какую ссылку нажали, и, если надо, открывать её в браузере.

Comment: Все приложение эта мобильная версия сайта упакованная в webview, чтобы не нарушать целостность все ссылки которые идут не на домен сайта нужно открывать в браузере, а не в приложение.